# JHipster prod build not able to create

Tags: node.js, npm, jhipster, npm-install

Getting below Error when creating prod build with fresh code generated through JHipster
User below options:
1.monolithic app 
2.Do you want to use the JHipster Registry to configure -- no
3. JWT authentication
4. H2 database with disk persistence
5.no cache
6 maven
7. websockets using spring
8. angular 4 
9. no css processor
10.no international
11. no testing framework
12.no other generators
using below command on windows
mvnw -Pprod

Also this command is installing the node and yarn locally

```
[INFO] [4/4] Building fresh packages...
[ERROR] error D:\ws\15_sep\node_modules\spawn-sync: Command failed.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
[ERROR] Exit code: 1
[ERROR] Command: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
[ERROR] Arguments: /d /s /c node postinstall
[ERROR] Directory: D:\ws\15_sep\node_modules\spawn-sync
[ERROR] Output:
[ERROR] module.js:471
[ERROR]     throw err;
[ERROR]     ^
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Error: Cannot find module 'D:\ws\15_sep\node_modules\spawn-sync\postinstall'
[ERROR]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
[ERROR]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
[ERROR]     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
[ERROR]     at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
[ERROR]     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
[ERROR]     at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

Answer (score 0):

currently i am able to create the build war file by first running the dev build by running below command

```
   npm install
```

and then remove the below execution from prod profile from pom.xml file
and then running the prod build

```
                      <execution>
                                <id>install node and yarn</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                                    <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>yarn install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>yarn</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
```

and then running the prod build

```
mvnw -Pprod
```

Comment: I'm confused why do you use `npm install` and then yarn in your pom? It's usually a bad idea to mix them up